# Getting Caused By: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match. while using X.509 client key and certificate

Tags: spring-vault

I am getting below exception when trying to use X.509 client certificate for accessing keys from Vault using spring-vault-code 2.3.3
aused By: java.security.SignatureException: Signature does not match.
at sun.security.x509.X509CertImpl.verify(X509CertImpl.java:449)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.verifySignature(BasicChecker.java:166)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.BasicChecker.check(BasicChecker.java:147)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXMasterCertPathValidator.java:125)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:238)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.validate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:146)
at sun.security.provider.certpath.PKIXCertPathValidator.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidator.java:85)
at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:292)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.doValidate(PKIXValidator.java:375)
at sun.security.validator.PKIXValidator.engineValidate(PKIXValidator.java:285)
at sun.security.validator.Validator.validate(Validator.java:262)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.validate(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:330)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:227)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:132)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1622)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:1037)
at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:965)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1064)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1395)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1379)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:376)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:109)
at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.lambda$getSessionInterceptor$1(VaultTemplate.java:255)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
at org.springframework.vault.client.RestTemplateBuilder.lambda$createTemplate$4(RestTemplateBuilder.java:239)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
at org.springframework.vault.client.VaultClients.lambda$createRestTemplate$0(VaultClients.java:122)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest$InterceptingRequestExecution.execute(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:93)
at org.springframework.http.client.InterceptingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(InterceptingClientHttpRequest.java:77)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultKeyValue2Accessor.lambda$list$0(VaultKeyValue2Accessor.java:59)
at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultKeyValueAccessor.lambda$doRead$2(VaultKeyValueAccessor.java:166)
at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultTemplate.doWithSession(VaultTemplate.java:448)
at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultKeyValueAccessor.doRead(VaultKeyValueAccessor.java:163)
at org.springframework.vault.core.VaultKeyValue2Accessor.list(VaultKeyValue2Accessor.java:58)
at com.oracle.healthinsurance.credentialstore.internal.vault.VaultConnectivityUtility.populateCacheFromVault(VaultConnectivityUtility.java:51)
at com.oracle.healthinsurance.credentialstore.internal.vault.VaultCredentialStore.populateCacheFromVault(VaultCredentialStore.java:121)
at com.oracle.healthinsurance.credentialstore.internal.vault.VaultCredentialStore.getCredentialKeys(VaultCredentialStore.java:60)
at com.oracle.healthinsurance.oauth.internal.CredentialStoreInitializer.onApplicationEvent(CredentialStoreInitializer.java:36)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.doInvoke(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:344)
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.processEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:229)
at org.springframework.context.event.ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.onApplicationEvent(ApplicationListenerMethodAdapter.java:166)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:421)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:391)
at com.oracle.healthinsurance.appstart.impl.OhiApplication.startup(OhiApplication.java:61)

Code snippet which I am using to connect/access vault
@Override
public VaultEndpoint vaultEndpoint() {

```
    try {
        return VaultEndpoint.from(new URI(vaultAddress));
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        logger.error(e, "Unable to connect VaultEndPoint : {0}", () -> objects(vaultAddress));
        throw new RuntimeException("Error while connecting to VaultEndPoint", e);
    }
}

@Override
public ClientAuthentication clientAuthentication() {

    return new TokenAuthentication(tokenCache.get(VAULT_TOKEN_CACHE_KEY).getToken());
}

@Override
public ClientOptions clientOptions(){
    return null;
}

@Override
public SslConfiguration sslConfiguration() {

    if (isNotEmpty(trustStoreResource)) {
        // 1. JKS trust store
        return useTrustStore(trustStoreResource, resourceLoader);
    } else if (isNotEmpty(keyStoreResource)) {
        // 2. JKS keystore
        return useKeyStore(keyStoreResource, keyStorePassword, resourceLoader);
    } else if (isNotEmpty(pemResource)) {
        // 3. PEM
        return usePem(pemResource, resourceLoader);
    } else if (isNotEmpty(clientPemResource) && isNotEmpty(clientKeyPemResource)) {
        // 4. client PEM and RSA key
        return useClientPem(clientPemResource, clientKeyPemResource, resourceLoader);
    }

    logger.trace("Return default SslConfiguration");
    return SslConfiguration.unconfigured();
}
```

---

static SslConfiguration useClientPem(final String pemLocation, final String keyPemLocation,
final ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {

```
    logger.debug("Initialize Vault using client PEM certificate");

    Resource resource = loadResource(resourceLoader, pemLocation);
    Resource clientResource = loadResource(resourceLoader, keyPemLocation);
    if (resource.isFile()) {
        if (clientResource.isFile()) {
            logger.trace("Found resource is file type");

            return new SslConfiguration(new SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration(clientResource, null, PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE),
                    new SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration(resource, null, PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE));
            //return SslConfiguration.create(clientResource, (char[]) null, resource, null);
            //sslConfiguration.withTrustStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(resource).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE)).withKeyStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(clientResource).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE));
             //return SslConfiguration
             //       .forTrustStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(resource).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE))
             //        .withKeyStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(clientResource).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE));
            //return sslConfiguration;
        } else {
            logger.trace("Found resource is not a file type");
            return SslConfiguration
                    .forTrustStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(resource).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE))
                    .withTrustStore(
                            SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(getPEM(clientResource)).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE));
        }
    } else {
        if (clientResource.isFile()) {
            logger.trace("Found resource is file type ");
            return SslConfiguration
                    .forTrustStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(getPEM(resource)).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE))
                    .withTrustStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(clientResource).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE));
        } else {
            logger.trace("Found resource is not a file type ");
            return SslConfiguration
                    .forTrustStore(SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(getPEM(resource)).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE))
                    .withTrustStore(
                            SslConfiguration.KeyStoreConfiguration.of(getPEM(clientResource)).withStoreType(PEM_KEYSTORE_TYPE));
        }
    }
}
```

---

vaultProvider.getVaultOperations().opsForKeyValue(getSystemProperty(OHI_VAULT_KV_SECRETS_ENGINE).getValue(),
VaultKeyValueOperationsSupport.KeyValueBackend.KV_2).list(path);

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).